# i have a problem with react native splash screen

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen, react-native-splash-screen

i'm having problems using react native splash screen. I follow the steps on the github repo but the problem stills.

My problem occurs after installing and configuring React Native Splash Screen in my application. I followed all the steps correctly, and when I launch the app, the image I chose is displayed. However, when navigating between screens, if the screen contains an Input tag (I use the NativeBase library, but I also tried with the React component and encountered the same error), the app crashes and displays the following error message:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDrpp.png)

build.gradle file:

[build gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhoYt.png)

settings.gradle file:

[settings gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io9Px.png)

MainActivity.java file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i6tR.png)

launch_screen.xml file:

[launch screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjgWl.png)

I repeat, the launch screen looks fine, the problem arises when I try to use input tags.

Any ideas ?? Or suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

i think you're missing this file:

[image]

and you should have this splashActivity inside you manifest

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. The problem is still there. However, the react-native-splash-screen docs don't mention anything about SplashActivity and the manifest file.

Comment: can you please share a repo on github to take a look on it?

Comment: I think the repo is this one: https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen
I'm having the same issue, but with React Native Paper. Also tested directly with TextInput from RN "vanilla".

Comment: Hi, i need to see you're code the complete project if it's possible. Not the react-native-splash-screen package.